# How do I change the default rotation of my VR controllers in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My VR Hands Are rotated in default rotation at 90 degrees idk why I was following the tutorial and I only used prefabs and modified them like in the videos. So I would like my hands to be normal and my hands look like that when I'm holding my VR controllers normally. I need suggestions to fix the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try rotating the (parent) object before pressing play, that usually works.
2. If you tried anything in the editor you can always force the rotation via code (take the rotation of the controller and rotate the hands 90 degrees from it)